# Powerpoint Interop: How to detect when a presentation is fully loaded

Tags: c#, .net, interop, powerpoint

I currently stuck on an issue that I can't resolve. When we have a worksheet in pptx, we get COM-Exceptions when saving. According to our tests, its because the Presentation is not yet fully loaded when we try to do a [SaveAs()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint._presentation.saveas(v=office.14).aspx) or [SaveCopyAs()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint._presentation.savecopyas(v=office.14).aspx).

However we noticed that there is no event or property in the [Presentation-Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.presentation_members(v=office.14).aspx) or [Application-Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.application_members(v=office.14).aspx), which might indicate when the Presentation is fully loaded. Nor does AddIn-Express (a plugin we use) have any event linked to that.

Is there way how we can test if all Shapes/Content in a presentation are fully loaded without resorting to amateuristic code like below:

**Current Dirty Fix:** (This code really hurts my eyes)

```
bool hasNotBeenSaved = true;
while (hasNotBeenSaved) {
    try {
        PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.SaveAs(filePath);
        hasNotBeenSaved = false;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log("AddInModule - PowerpointPanel - SaveAs() Enter exception clause");
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The COM Exception might be caused because the PPTX file didnt close properly from the previous Open state. Can you try the Marshal.ReleaseCOMObject(object) method after you save the pptx file and try again if its throwing error?. Your code would be something like,

```
  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(powerPointApp);
```

for reference please see  [Marshal.releaseCOMObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject(v=vs.110).aspx)

Note: You might also have to make sure that in your task manager no PPTX instances are running, if they are forcefully "End" them by selecting them and clicking on "End Task".

Hope this Helps! Thanks!

Comment: The error is thrown on the SaveAs(). The file must remain open at all times. So I can't really release any COMObjects. There is also only one Powerpoint.exe - process running.